# Why are records disappearing mid-test in my rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing

I have two models, lets call them A and B. Creating a new A record will sometimes trigger the creation of a B record.

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create { |a| B.create_for(a) if a.needs_b? }
end
```

in my test file I have

```
class TapeTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  self.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  test "something" do
    assert_equal(0, B.count)
    a = A.create(:foo => "bar")
    assert_equal(1, B.count)
  end
end
```

and the test fails on the second assertion, even though this works if I copy it over to the console. When I add a `debugger` call in the `B.create_for` method, the B record is indeed being created. It shows up in the db and everything, but as soon as execution returns to the `test "something"` block, it goes away! I turned transactional_fixtures off to try and solve this, but it doesn't help.

EDIT: turning transactional fixtures on actually solves this problem but breaks way more tests than it fixes. Assume it needs to be off.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's going on for sure but I'd try doing A.create!(...) to see if there is an exception being raised there that's causing a rollback.

Comment: Good suggestion. I checked it out and A.create! doesn't return an exception.